# Does node-chakracore support WASM (Web Assembly)?

Tags: node.js, webassembly, chakracore

Can I deploy the same WASM javascript modules to node-chakracore as I can to nodejs v8?

Answer (score 1):

ChakraCore has supported WebAssembly since v1.4, and node-chakracore has supported it via JavaScript since 8.x:

> WASM is supported in Node-ChakraCore if you're using the WebAssembly
>   methods from JavaScript. Using basic.wasm from here, the following
>   code worked with Node-ChakraCore:

```
const fs = require('fs'); const buf = fs.readFileSync('basic.wasm')

async function test() {
    try {
        const module = await WebAssembly.compile(buf);
        const inst = new WebAssembly.Instance(module, {test: {foo: function(a){console.log(`foo called: ${a}`); return 2;}}});
        console.log(inst.exports.a(1));
    } catch (reason) { 
        console.log(`Failed: ${reason}`)
    } }

test();
```

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/pull/1777#discussion_r127280773

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [node-wasm](https://github.com/yusinto/node-wasm) to load your wasm file and then in your node js app, do this:

```
import loadWasm from 'node-wasm';

async function run() {
  const {rust_function} = await loadWasm('/local/path/to/wasm');
  const result = rust_function();
  console.log(result);
}

run();
```

There's a complete example [here](https://github.com/yusinto/node-wasm/tree/master/example/node) in the same repo. Good luck!